# Gulp-eslint throws errors on dynamically loaded JSs

Tags: gulp-eslint

I have a project structure like

[image: Folder Structure]

There are approx 10 JS files in `com`. `lab1` and `lab2` has a `config.json` file which tells, out of 10 files which files to be concatenated and placed as `app-min.js` in `dist/lab1` or `dist/lab2`.

In the gulp file I've created something like this.

```
var filesArr = [];
var labName;

// Player Task
gulp.task('player', function () {
  return gulp.src(filesArr)
    .pipe(eslint())
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(concat('app-min.js'))
    .pipe(uglify({
      compress: {
        drop_console: true
      }
    }).on('error', gutil.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/' + labName));
});

// Clean
gulp.task('clean', function () {
  if (readJson()) {
    return del([
      'dist/' + labName
    ]);
  }
  return null;
});

// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function () {
  gulp.watch(filesArr, gulp.series('player'));
});

// Read Json and create JS Array
function readJson() {
  // LAB STRUCTURE
  var _n = prompt('Specify the LAB name. ');
  labName = _n;
  var _path = path.resolve('./src/' + _n);
  var _exists = fs.existsSync(_path);
  if (_exists) {
    var _json = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(_path + '/labstructure.json'), 'utf-8');
    var _jObj = JSON.parse(_json).labObj.components;
    for (var i = 0; i < _jObj.length; i++) {
      var _jsName = 'src/com/component/' + _jObj[i].ref + '.js';
      if (filesArr.indexOf(_jsName) === -1) {
        filesArr.push(_jsName);
      }
    }
  }
  return _exists;
}

gulp.task('default', gulp.series('clean', 'player', 'watch'));
```

Here the `filesArr` looks like:

```
[ 'src/com/component/ColorActClass.js',
  'src/com/component/PanelCompClass.js',
  'src/com/component/ToggleCompClass.js',
  'src/com/component/SliderCompClass.js',
  'src/com/component/CheckBoxCompClass.js',
  'src/com/component/ButtonCompClass.js',
  'src/com/component/LabelCompClass.js',
  'src/com/component/InputBoxClass.js',
  'src/com/component/ColorMonitorClass.js',
  'src/com/component/MsgBoxClass.js',
  'src/com/component/ConfBoxClass.js',
  'src/com/component/NumberPadClass.js',
  'src/com/main/lib/webfontloader.js',
  'src/com/main/lib/howler.core.min.js',
  'src/com/main/PlayerClass.js',
  'src/kl1001_color/BrainClass.js' ]
```

This works perfectly fine at the first place. But when any JS is modified then in `watch` `player` task throws `eslint` error on some files which are untouched. This doesn't happen always rather if watch is running for 10-20 mins then it throws error. Like this:

[image: Error Image]

In this case `CheckBoxCompClass.js` is not the file which is modified, but still got the issue. On top of that, the semicolon is in place. If this file has issue then `eslint` should have thrown the error at the first place.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally, my NVM was set to an older version. Solved the issue after updating the NVM and by setting the current NVM version to the latest one.